# How to set text boundaries in Graphics2D Java?

Tags: java, swing, text, graphics2d

Is there any simple way to set a boundary for text on one side in Graphics2D for Java? For example, I have a rank card that displays a player's rank, and as the rank # increases in size, I want the line to expand backwards, not forwards. As you can see in the image, "Rank #24" is lined up perfectly with a line below it. If this number ever becomes 3 or 4 digits long, I want the text to get pushed backwards so the end still lines up perfectly with the line below.

Is there a simple way to do this with Graphics2D, or should I just calculate the shift myself based on how large the rank number is?

[image]

Comment: _Is there a simple way to do this with Graphics2D_ As far as I know, there isn't. _or should I just calculate the shift myself based on how large the rank number is?_ Yes, you should. If you don't know how to calculate the shift, refer to the answer from @camickr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `FontsMetrics` class of your `Graphics` object in the `paintComponent()` method to get the size of the String.

Then you calculate the starting point for painting the String based on the width and your desired end point:

```
FontMetrice fm = graphics.getFontMetrics();
int width = fm.stringWidth("Rank #1235");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)